# Best way to store different structs in same array in c

Tags: arrays, c, struct

If I have multiple structs which have a common method like this:

```
typedef struct s sphere;
typedef struct s{
    point3 center;
    double radius;
    bool (*hit)(sphere, const ray*, double, double, hit_record*);

} sphere;

typedef struct b box;
typedef struct b{
    point3 center;
    double radius;
    bool (*hit)(box, const ray*, double, double, hit_record*);

} box;
```

Is it possible for me to create some type of array such that it can store both of these structs and loop through it calling the method like this:

```
objects shapes[50]; // Where objects is something that can let shapes hold both structs


//Pretend shapes has a mixture of Boxes and Spheres
int number_of_shapes = 20;

for (int i = 0; i < number_of_shapes;i++){
    if shapes[i].hit(shapes[i], r, t, t, red) { //random variables
        ;// do something
    }
}
```

I just started learning c yesterday so I am not really sure what to do. I tried using void pointers but that also failed miserably.

Comment: Create a union of both structs. Then another struct incorporating this union and a type marker. Then you can make an array of these nested monsters.

Comment: As Eugene says, but also consider the necessity of some kind of dispatch (eg `switch( object.type )`) to cast the generic object into the correct type to invoke its particular `hit()` handler... In the end, there's no need for the "ptr to function" in each instance of an object...

Comment: Please post code that can be compiled

Comment: Also the 2 `struct` are identical if you pass a pointer to the structure in the function,  and not a value. But this is something you should anyway do, `void*` is he way to go but here it does not seem that you even need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Void pointers are the right way to do that, but it requires that your objects are persistent in memory, because an array of pointers won't retain them. I give you an example :

EDIT : I update the example to do the job using function pointers and simulate the behavior of methods.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Type your code here, or load an example.
enum { TypeSphere, TypeBox };

typedef struct s sphere;
typedef struct b box;
typedef char (*hit)(void *object, void *ray, double x, double y, void*hit_record);

// Starts both structure with a common function pointer type
typedef struct s{
    hit method;
    double center;
    double radius;
} sphere;


typedef struct b{
    hit method;
    double center;
    double radius;
} box;

// Implementation of a method for each type
char sphereMethod(void *s, void *ray, double x, double y, void *hit_record) { 
    printf("A sphere\n"); 
}
char boxMethod(void *b, void *ray, double x, double y, void *hit_record) { 
    printf("A box\n");
}

int main() {
    void* objects[50];
    
    // Allocates 25 objects of each type for the example
    for(int i=0; i<50; i+=2) {
        objects[i] = malloc(sizeof(sphere));
        // Sets the implementation here
        ((sphere *)objects[i])->method = sphereMethod;
        objects[i+1] = malloc(sizeof(box));
        ((box *)objects[i+1])->method = boxMethod;
    }
    // Loops through objects and calls the methods
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) { 
        hit method = *((hit *)objects[i]);
        method(objects[i], NULL, 0, 0, NULL);
    }
    
    // Frees them
    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) { free(objects[i]); }
}
```

Comment: So I must use a switch statement? I am aiming to generalize this to at least 10-15 objects so I wanted to avoid it.

Comment: See my edit : It shows an example simulating the behavior of methods using function pointers. However I don't see any solution to avoid having a specific named function to implement each specialized method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I will try looking deeper but this solves my needs for now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough cut of how you might achieve your objective...

```
enum { BOX, SPHERE } types;

typedef struct sphere {
    point3 center;
    double radius;
} sphere_t;

typedef struct box {
    point3 center;
    double len, wid, dpth;
    double rotX, rotY, rotZ;
} box_t;

typedef object {
    int type;
    union {
        sphere_t sphere;
        box_t box;
    };
} object_t;

int main() {
    object_t objs[ 50 ];
    /* ... */
    for( int i = 0; i < numObjs; i++ )
        switch( objs[ i ].type ) {
            case BOX:
                hndlr_Box( objs[i].box );
                break;
            case SPHERE:
                hndlr_Sphere( objs[i].sphere );
                break;
            /* ... */
        }
}
```

Looking back at that, it might be even better to use a linked list of objects instead of an array.

AND, each object instance in the array will consume as much memory as is required for the largest of the union. It may be better to use pointers to separately allocated blocks, each storing only its particular attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a sufficiently complicated enough object, you should be able to accomplish something pretty close to your goal. Below, I sketch out a solution that you should be able to build upon.

First, we define a `Shape` as having a `ShapeInterface`, which for now is just something that can be `hit`.

```
typedef struct HitRecord HitRecord;
typedef struct Ray Ray;

typedef struct Shape {
    const struct ShapeInterface * const vtable;
} Shape;

struct ShapeInterface {
    bool (*hit)(Shape *, const Ray *, double, double, HitRecord *);
    void (*dump)(Shape *);
};

bool shape_hit (Shape *s, const Ray *r, double x, double y, HitRecord *hr) {
    return s->vtable->hit(s, r, x, y, hr);
}

void shape_dump (Shape *s) {
    s->vtable->dump(s);
}
```

Then, we define `Sphere` and `Box` to be kinds of `Shape`.

```
typedef struct Point3 {
    double p[3];
} Point3;

typedef struct Sphere {
    Shape base;
    Point3 center;
    double radius;
    bool popped;
} Sphere;

typedef struct Box {
    Shape base;
    Point3 center;
    double radius;
    bool crushed;
} Box;
```

Now, define `Objects` to be a union of these different kinds of `Shape`. We note that all items in `Objects` have a common initial sequence, which is `Shape`.

```
typedef union Objects {
    Shape shape;
    Sphere sphere;
    Box box;
} Objects;
```

When you have an array of `Objects`, you can loop through and call `shape_hit` on the `shape` member.

```
void process_hit_objects (
        Objects shapes[],
        int number_of_shapes,
        const Ray *r, double x, double y, HitRecord *hr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_shapes; ++i) {
        if (shape_hit(&shapes[i].shape, r, x, y, hr)) {
            /* ... do something ... */
            shape_dump(&shapes[i].shape);
        }
    }
}
```

When creating a `Sphere`, it needs to initialize its `base` member with an appropriate implementations for the functions in its `vtable`.

```
static bool sphere_hit (
        Shape *shape, const Ray *r, double x, double y, HitRecord *hr) {
    Sphere *sphere = (void *)shape;
    return sphere->popped;
}

static void sphere_dump (Shape *shape) {
    Sphere *sphere = (void *)shape;
    double *p = sphere->center.p;
    printf("sphere: %p @ <%f,%f,%f> |%f|\n",
           (void *)sphere, p[0], p[1], p[2], sphere->radius);
}

void makeSphere (Sphere *s, Point3 center, double radius) {
    static const struct ShapeInterface vtable = {
        sphere_hit, sphere_dump
    };
    Shape base = { &vtable };
    Sphere sphere = { base, center, radius, true };
    memcpy(s, &sphere, sizeof(sphere));
}
```

Similarly for a `Box`.

```
static bool box_hit (
        Shape *shape, const Ray *r, double x, double y, HitRecord *hr) {
    Box *box = (void *)shape;
    return box->crushed;
}

static void box_dump (Shape *shape) {
    Box *box = (void *)shape;
    double *p = box->center.p;
    printf("box: %p @ <%f,%f,%f> |%f|\n",
           (void *)box, p[0], p[1], p[2], box->radius);
}

void makeBox (Box *b, Point3 center, double radius) {
    static const struct ShapeInterface vtable = {
        box_hit, box_dump
    };
    Shape base = { &vtable };
    Box box = { base, center, radius, true };
    memcpy(b, &box, sizeof(box));
}
```